# The constructor Random() is not visible

Tags: java, gwt

I am creating a gwt application.I get the error "The constructor Random() is not visible" in the method below.I have tried putting it in the main onModuleLoad() as well.

```
public void jump(){
 Random generator = new Random();
}
```

I have imported random via the following

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Random;
```

No matter where I put this I still keep getting that error.

Thanks

Comment: I got it working by importing java.util.Random.But that just seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't instantiate it. Instead, call the static methods on the class:

```
Random.nextInt(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `com.google.gwt.user.client.Random` class has no public constructor, and all of its methods are static.  The javadoc says:

> This class can be used as a substitute for java.util.Random. The semantics differ in that the underlying browser's implementation is used. The random generator cannot be seeded or otherwise used to reproduce a particular sequence of results.

I suspect that the reason for this design (i.e. static methods and no public constructor) is that the GWT `Random` class is really just a skin for the ECMAScript function `Math.random()`,  which is a *static* function and which cannot be seeded.

I guess using `java.util.Random` is an alternative, but I would not trust it to be able to seed itself from a browser-side source of entropy.